# Insert a formula in a cell, depending on the value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula do I need to put in B1 B2 etc. to get the formula to do nothing if cell A has an entry but if empty put the value of the cell above in the cell?

The If formula answers the question, but what can I use to poke a formula into cell B to get the result.

Example:
Cell `A1` is a date say 24/02/17.
Cell `B1` is the formula `If(a1>0, "do nothing")`, "put in content of cell A above).

Cell `A2` is blank
Cell `B2` is the formula `If(a2>0, 24/02/17`

I could do it in Visual Basic, can I do it with a formula?

Answer (score 0):

B1 the formula would not work, since you are at the top of your sheet.
B2 you could put the formula =IF(A2=0,A1)

Using your original if, =IF(A2>0,,A1).  Remeber If format is (evaluation,if True,if False)

As you copy and paste, A2 will become A3 and A1, A2, so on and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISBLANK`

In your explanation, that will be

```
   A  |  B
1     |
2     | =IF(ISBLANK(A2), B1, )
```

Your formula is wrong

`If(a1>0, "do nothing"), "put in content of cell A above)`

will not work like

`to do nothing if cell A has an entry but if empty put the value of the cell above in the cell`